# Can I use React for my UI on a Wordpress project?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, user-interface, deployment, frontend

I have been playing with wordpress lately and I managed to deploy a simple page via a web hosting company (whc) with a domain name and everything. I love working with React and I am looking to understand how it would work in order to use WordPress with React. I played a bit with the ReactPress plugin and went through some ressources online but I am still unsuccesfull. From my understanding they are two main ways to do such a thing and I think I am mixing them up. I was wondering if there is a clear way to do so. Any info will be very welcome

Comment: just use iframe tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a React framework for WordPress. You may check that.

https://frontity.org/ have a look

Comment: Its perfect Zeeshan. Thanks.